# How to get number of CPU or thread are using when use psutil.popen()?

Tags: python, multithreading, cpu-usage, popen, psutil

I have a python script, which using `psutil.popen()` to execute another binary program.

```
proc = psutil.Popen(
        "/bin/<some_program>",
        stdout=sys.stdout,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        shell=True,
        executable="/bin/csh",
)
```

Question:
How can I get the number of CPU or thread that `proc` are using?

I know some answers in StackOverflow said that cpu_times() or cpu_percent()
can get the cpu usage. However, these numbers are not 'integer'. They are utilization rate.

I am using the following code now, but I'm not sure whether the output is correct or not. Since the output always is '1'.

```
peak_cpu = subprocess.check_output(f"ls /proc/{proc.pid}/task | wc -l",
shell=True).decode("utf-8")

while proc.poll() is None:
    cpu = subprocess.check_output(f"ls /proc/{proc.pid}/task | wc -l",
    shell=True).decode("utf-8")
    if cpu > peak_cpu:
        peak_cpu = cpu
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is it you want to know?  Your post is quite confusing.  You can't find out how many CPUs a proc is using; that information changes from millisecond to millisecond.  You can find out how many threads it has, and you can find out what percent of the CPU it used over the last second.  Why do you think you need this?

Comment: @TimRoberts OK,  I would like to know how many threads the process is using. I need this information because I want to benchmark the peak_cpu(or say, peak_thread) for the <some_program>

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?  `proc.num_threads()` tells you how many threads it has, but that is unrelated to performance.  Lots of apps have many threads that sit in the background doing nothing, waiting for I/O to complete.  `p.cpu_times()` and `p.cpu_percent` can get you the other information.